# @use in sass - Unable to resolve path of css from node_modules

Tags: css, angular, sass, sass-loader, normalize-css

I have installed modern-normalize in my project, and from a sass file I'm trying to include it's css file like so:

```
@use '~modern-normalize/modern-normalize' as *;
```

I keep getting this however:

> Error: Can't find stylesheet to import.   ╷ 9 │ @use
> '~modern-normalize/modern-normalize' as *;   │
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Even though in my IDE (vscode) I can CMD+Click on this and it navigates and opens the file just fine, I see in my node_modules dir

Am I missing something config related perhaps?

Comment: Did you try with absolute path?

Answer (score 0):

Your path looks odd, the tilde `~` prefix start of the path tells used to css-loader to resolve the import "like a module", starting from the node_modules directory.

However Angular has deprecated the use of `~` for Sass `@use` and `@import` statements.

> Tilde imports have been deprecated in the Sass loader for a long time
> and they won't work with the new package format in v13. These changes
> add a migration that will drop the tilde.

See https://github.com/angular/components/commit/f2ff9e31425f0e395e6926bcaf48f876688000d8

So try removing it. e.g.

```
@use 'modern-normalize/modern-normalize' as *;
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular has removed tilde support for sass loader. Do this in angular.json for your application to add relative path to node modules

```
 "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
   "includePaths": [
     "./node_modules"
   ]
 }
```

Then remove ~ from your import paths.

Alternatively, you can use absolute path for import such as below, construct path to node_modules, you might need to check correct path for your file.

```
use '../../node_modules/modern-normalize/modern-normalize' as *;
```

Comment: That is not an absolute path but a relative path. Still it's not the preferred path.